# how do you make an action that draws a dot shape every time you tap

Tags: iphone, xcode4, drawing

you can try my app if you want this are 2 promo codes:
JMYMRWL4AXX7
4ATFK6XWAWXL

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ianamnesi/id426778210?mt=8

I want to improve it with, so basically I want to be able to do the signature with the finger on the UIImageView on the scrollView

I need  an action that draws a dot shape every time I tap on my UIImageView

```
-(IBAction)drawdot:(id)sender{}
```

thanks

what I got so far:

basically I have a scrollview with some buttons on it and on the bottom of the scrollview I added an UIImageView, were I want to write with fingers.
Because the scrolView is difficult, so I had to add UILongPressureGesturesRecongnizer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1540)];

scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = YES;
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRec = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
((UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRec).minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
((UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRec).numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
(( UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRec).allowableMovement = NO;
[drawImage addGestureRecognizer:gestureRec];

[gestureRec release];  

[super viewDidLoad];
mouseMoved = 0;
mouseSwiped = YES;

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    button.enabled = YES;


UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(printItem) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(75, 0, 44, 44);
```

[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"print.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];

}

now my UIIMageView recognise the long touch, so when I touch for 0.5 sec it make this action:

```
- (void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
UIView *theSuperview = self.view; // whatever view contains your image views
CGPoint touchPointInSuperview = [sender locationInView:theSuperview];
UIView *touchedView = [theSuperview hitTest:touchPointInSuperview withEvent:nil];
if([touchedView isKindOfClass:[drawImage class]])
{
    // action for making a dot 
}
```

}

now I had to include something that makes dot when I tap, and because the longPressureGestureRecognize when I move the finger it recognise it as multiple taps..

thanks

Comment: Draws a dot at the location of the tap in the image view?

Comment: I'd need some code if you can share it, please.

Answer (score 2):

You're not taking a very realistic approach toward learning how to develop software for a given platform. What have you tried (beyond an empty method)? What have you read in the vast Cocoa documentation?

Your goal: A UIView that responds to touch events, figures out their coordinates, and flags itself as needing to display, then (in its drawing routine that is called by the OS if and when appropriate) draws some shape.

There are several major, high-profile developer guides in Apple's documentation that deal with [responding to touch events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/EventHandlingStartingPoint/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010755) and with [drawing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156). All of these are referenced in the basic "getting started" material. Have you read them? Have you at least skimmed them? If you have, what didn't you understand / where did you get stuck? If you haven't, you should adjust your expectations: read the documentation and ask more specific questions like everybody else.

Without displaying at least some effort on your part, your questions are most likely to be ignored entirely.

Comment: I tried to improve my question. Can u have a look. thanks